# Does anyone agree that there is ambiguity in the term 'automated' wrt retention labels and the relationship to E3/E5 licencing

Tags: retention, licence

As I understand it, a user can manually apply a retention label to a piece of content in SPO within an E3 licence, but an E5 licence is required if the retention label was applied automatically. But does it matter **where** or **by what** the retention label is applied automatically? If it was applied automatically by a feature within SP, then fair enough, a premium feature has been used and additional licence payment is due, but what if an external script created the retention label using (say) the Sharepoint SDK? Wouldn't that be using the SDK as intended, not using a premium feature within SP and, as a consequence, permissible within an E3 licence?

Moreover, I've heard rumblings on the grapevine that MS might be looking to tighten up on this kind of thing, so even if it was acceptable previously (and, indeed, might be as of today), it might change in the future. It seems to me that an SP user who had invested in a bespoke add on to create retention labels within an E3 licence would be up a creek without a paddle - they might either have to stump up for the E5 licence, or delete what might be zillions of retention labels, with no Plan B.

Do any of you have any views on a) the validity of creating retention labels using an external 3rd party add-on within an E3 licence and b) any gossip that MS may be looking to get more stringent in this area?

TIA